# Some CSS not loading

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some css loaded in a `cshtml` file so that I can use razor syntax to define some colours. An ActionResult called `CustomCss` returns the file as a partial view. This works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE, some of the styles don't load--if I inspect the element in chrome, it lists that `CustomCss` file in the element's styles, but doing the same in firefox reveals the file *not* being in that list. The fact that *some* styles do get loaded is confusing me.

What could be the problem?

**Action**

```
public ActionResult CustomCss()
{
    Response.ContentType = "text/css";
    return PartialView("css/custom.css");
}
```

**Linking the stylesheet**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Action("CustomCss", "Home")" />
```

Comment: Why are you returning the css files as a partial view?

Comment: So that it would get loaded first I assume...I didn't actually write that action.

Comment: In your _Layoutfile can't you add `@RenderSection("css", false)` in the `<head>` and then in your view do `@section css { <link href="@Url.Content("/path/to/file")" rel="stylesheet"> }`

Comment: Firefox and IE could also be cached causing the css files not to load.  In Firefox and IE10 you can clear your cache by pressing àlt + shift + delete` and selecting "clear cache."

Comment: @Andrew The cache isn't causing the problem, but I am doing both the `RenderSection` and `<link href` thing--using `@Url.Content("/path/to/file")` versus the `@Url.Action("CustomCss", "Home")` I'm using now both don't work (the path version doesn't render anything at all).

Comment: If that didn't fix it you can go ahead and take it back out.  Can you post your code for the action and the view?

Comment: Just to double check, if you look at the source code in Firefox/IE the custom.css is not listed there?

Comment: What if you change your `link`to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("css/custom.css")" />` just to test it out.  If that doesn't work, copy it to the head to see if it works there.

Comment: Doesn't work no matter where it is unfortunately.

Comment: Are you testing locally or on a server?

Comment: @Andrew Locally. And to add more detail to the 'looking at source code' thing which I might have misunderstood: the file is loaded in there (I can see in it Firefox's Style Editor), and I can see all the rules for listed. Some of them just aren't being applied for whatever reason, so when I select an element that does not 'work', I do not see the custom css listed in its styles.

Comment: You may need to add `!important` for the styles that aren't being applied.

Comment: @Andrew Still doesn't work--they aren't just not being applied, it's like they're not even there with respect to the element (eg. it's not being overwritten by another style rule, it's just not there at all). That said, they /are/ there in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh it was just a syntax error.

I missed it when I first looked in Firefox's console, but apparently I had been missing one quote at the end of a rule class, which then essentially invalidated everything after it. Chrome was completely okay with this, but that quote was what was causing the 'things aren't loading' effect in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Some styles tend not to work like background gradient on other browsers.

```
You have to add additional CSS 
/* Safari 4-5, Chrome 1-9 */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

/* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

/* Firefox 3.6+ */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

/* IE 10 */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not this problem; I've tried putting just `border: 1px solid black` and that does not show up.